# MDCardSwipe swipe functionality not working

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I can't seem to make MDCardSwipe work. Even the sample code lifted directly from the documentation within kivymd.uix.card does not work on my machine.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCardSwipe

KV = '''
<SwipeToDeleteItem>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: content.height

    MDCardSwipeLayerBox:
        # Content under the card.

    MDCardSwipeFrontBox:

        # Content of card.
        OneLineListItem:
            id: content
            text: root.text
            _no_ripple_effect: True


MDScreen:

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "10dp"

        MDToolbar:
            elevation: 10
            title: "MDCardSwipe"

        ScrollView:
            scroll_timeout : 100

            MDList:
                id: md_list
                padding: 0
'''


class SwipeToDeleteItem(MDCardSwipe):
    '''Card with `swipe-to-delete` behavior.'''

    text = StringProperty()


class TestCard(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def build(self):
        return self.screen

    def on_start(self):
        '''Creates a list of cards.'''

        for i in range(20):
            self.screen.ids.md_list.add_widget(
                SwipeToDeleteItem(text=f"One-line item {i}")
            )


TestCard().run()
```

The above code on my machine creates the cards in a list, but there is no swipe functionality. I have also tried playing around with swipe_distance and swipe_type but have been unable to ever get the swipe functionality working.

Comment: Look at the documentation again and scroll down a bit further. The code you have copied is not the functioning code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into the same problem myself.

I would advise looking at the 'end code' from the [MDCardSwipe docs](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/card/index.html#mdcardswipe), run it and you'll probably have the same issue as in your original question.

You'll notice that if (on pc) you long press at the left edge and then drag the swipe functionality is there, just incredibly difficult to trigger.

I believe this is due to competition between the scrollview and the child widgets for the input, I solved the problem by adjusting [`scroll_timeout`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.scroll_timeout).

Comment: You were right, I just needed to swipe from the very very edge rather than throughout the length of the card. Thank you!